# iPhone: launch app with YouTube URL?

Tags: iphone, url, url-scheme

I want to register a custom URL scheme that will enable my app to be launched whenever the user goes to a YouTube URL (`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER`) in the browser.

Is this possible?

---

**Edit:**

After poking around I realized that YouTube's URL scheme is simply `youtube://`. What I want to do is that whenever there is a call to YouTube with the URL scheme, I want my app to be launched instead of the YouTube app - is this possible? What happens when there are conflicting URL schemes?

Answer (score 1):

URL scheme is the thing preceding `://`. It means you can't assign your app to handle youtube urls or any other `http` urls.

**Update**

Although Apple mentions YouTube URL Scheme in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1), in the context of implementing custom URL schemes only the part before `://` can be specified.

**Update 2**

Regarding your updated question. I'm pretty sure Apple wants YouTube app launched for `youtube://` URLs. Since I haven't found an explicit note about conflicting URL schemes, I can't tell how the OS chooses an app to launch in general for a custom URL scheme.

As for the URLs handled by the built-in apps, they are very likely to remain so, i.e. it's impossible to override a built-in app and handle an `http://` or a `youtube://` URL with your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that and it will work on the simulator but the app will never get past the App review process.

On a side note, why would you want to do such thing as redirect youtube urls to your app, it's at least confusing to the user.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that? Because each time I try to use youtube://, the youtube app is launched (Although I explicitly defined the url scheme of MY app to be youtube://).

Comment: [If more than one third-party application registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which application will be given that scheme.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html)